# Github Secrets Local Override

Tags: github, overriding, local, github-actions, github-secret

I'm currently working on a project which uses Github secrets to encrypt variables used in unit and int. tests. As the tests are part of the build cycle, they will pass when run through Github CI pipeline and the secrets can be accessed, but will fail locally.

How can I override these Github secrets with other values to run the build locally?

Comment: Have you tried defining them in a `.env` file in the root?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?